# Umbraco - set document publicly accessible via web services

Tags: web-services, umbraco, umbraco-blog

The question regarding the Umbraco CMS:

I have to setup public access for particular document (a blog, for example) programmatically - using web services exposed by Umbraco (Document service, Member service, etc.). I suppose that services are suitable for CRUD operations only, but I am not sure, as they let setting document properties in a flexible way.

Does someone have any experience with this and can you help me implement this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS. What I mean about 'Setup public access' - pointing those member groups (roles) that have access to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webservices that sit in the /umbraco/webservies/api/ directory work directly with database (this is bypassing the in-memory XML, and will hit the database with every request)
These API's are only available to users you supply in /config/umbraco.config

I'm guessing you want to return a bunch of data through JSON or XML, Umbraco base would be suitable http://umbraco.org/documentation/books/introduction-to-base

Comment: The target was pointed in my comment to the previous post - I wanted to rule the public access policy of the blog. And the '/Base' feature of the Umbraco is great for extending the CMS accordingly to my wish, thank you a lot!